# How to add Sherlock Action Bar to Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to make a project with tabbed action bar and all the codes I found crash on my device, because tab has been deprecated.

So I am trying to add the Sherlock action bar, but it is not in the Maver Repository.

Comment: The fact that APIs are deprecated does not cause code referencing those APIs to crash. Jake Wharton deprecated ActionBarSherlock itself about two years ago.

Comment: So I should stick to the default ActionBar?

Comment: Either use the native action bar or the `appcompat-v7` backport of the action bar. Then, use some other tab solution: `TabLayout`, a tab indicator for a `ViewPager`, `FragmentTabHost`, etc.